# Escritura en ficheros en C++

Tags: c++

El siguiente código compila y corre sin errores, pero al escribirse los datos en el archivo de texto aparecen en símbolos ASCII.

¿Por qué sucede esto?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#define strlen 20
using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    int number;
    int cost;
    int quantity;
}  PRICE, *LPPRICE;

int main()
{
    int size;
    cout << "Enter number of structures: ";
    cin >> size;
    cout << "-----------------------------------\n" << endl;

    LPPRICE pm = new PRICE[size];
    int index;
    FILE *file;

    if ((file = fopen("D:\\8.txt", "wb")) == NULL) { printf("Error opening file.\n"); exit(1); }

    for (index = 0; index<size; index++)
    {
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Number of orden: "; cin >> pm[index].number;
        cout << "Product cost: "; cin >> pm[index].cost;
        cout << "Quantity in stock: "; cin >> pm[index].quantity;
        cout << "-----------------------------------\n" << endl;
        fwrite(&pm[index], sizeof(PRICE), 1, file);
    }
    fclose(file);
    delete[]pm;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fwrite(&pm[index], sizeof(PRICE), 1, file);
```

En esa línea estás volcando el contenido *en binario* al fichero.

Cuando tu haces:

```
int variable = 5;
```

En memoria se almacena el número en binario, es decir: `0...0101`, que en 32 bits y hexadecimal sería `00 00 00 05`. Si tu entonces vuelcas el valor tal cual en un fichero lo que vas a almacenar es una secuencia de cuatro caracteres: 3 nulos y el caracter no imprimible 0x05.

Si lo que quieres es escribir en el fichero en formato texto puedes optar por usar `fprintf` para formatear la salida o bien puedes optar por usar `ofstream`, objeto propio de c++ para escribir ficheros.

En el caso de `fprintf`, más compatible con lo que tienes, el código quedaría así:

```
for (index = 0; index<size; index++)
{
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Number of orden: "; cin >> pm[index].number;
    cout << "Product cost: "; cin >> pm[index].cost;
    cout << "Quantity in stock: "; cin >> pm[index].quantity;
    cout << "-----------------------------------\n" << endl;
    fprintf(file, "%d %d %d\n", pm[index].number, pm[index].cost, pm[index].quantity);
}
```

En el caso de usar ofstream, podrías hacer algo similar a:

```
ofstream file;
file.open ("D:\\8.txt");

for (index = 0; index<size; index++)
{
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Number of orden: "; cin >> pm[index].number;
    cout << "Product cost: "; cin >> pm[index].cost;
    cout << "Quantity in stock: "; cin >> pm[index].quantity;
    cout << "-----------------------------------\n" << endl;

    file << pm[index].number << ' ' << pm[index].cost << ' ' << pm[index].quantity << '\n';
}

file.close();
```

Por cierto, en C++ las estructuras deberían estar declaradas así:

```
struct PRICE
{
    int number;
    int cost;
    int quantity;
};
```

Y el alias del puntero:

```
typedef PRICE* LPPRICE;
```

Esto último a partir del estándar C++11 (estándar liberado en 2011) podría quedar también así:

```
using LPPRICE = PRICE*;
```

Te recomiendo no usar la sintaxis propia de C en proyectos de C++.

Comment: Una pregunta, usando el caso fprintf al escribirase en el archivo se escribe todo en la misma línea, aun estando escrito '\n' en el código.

Comment: Claro, el salto de línea está al final. Si quieres almacenar cada número en una línea diferente has de poner un salto de línea entre medias: `"%d\n%d\n%d\n"`

Answer (score 0):

Sucede por que fopen al hacer w significa que vas a escribir cadena de texto (texto plano), sin embargo si tu deseas guardar los bytes binarios (la representación binaria de números, etc) deberás colocar la letra b al momento de abrir.

```
if ((file = fopen("D:\\8.txt", "wb")) == NULL) { printf("Error opening file.\n"); exit(1); }
```

Comment: Lo eh probado, pero sigue escribiendose en símbolos.

Comment: Que es lo que deseas entonces? te aparecerán simbolos por que son datos binarios, y los procesadores de texto querran convertirlo a texto, sin embargo te recomiendo busques un editor hexadecimal, y aparecerán los datos como tu deseas.

Comment: Si abres el fichero (da igual que esa modo texto o modo binario) y guardas datos binarios éstos no se van a convertir por arte de magia en modo texto. Entre otras cosas esto no es posible porque la interfaz de `FILE*` no sabe qué es lo que estás guardando.