# Leer string y floats de un archivo para calcular promedio ponderado en C++

Tags: c++

Buen día!
Esta pregunta es una continuación de la que hice hace unas semanas: [Cómo usar Arrays y loops para calcular el promedio ponderado de la universidad?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/62817/c%C3%B3mo-usar-arrays-y-loops-para-calcular-el-promedio-ponderado-de-la-universidad#)

En esa pregunta se usaron Loops y Arrays para el cálculo del promedio ponderado de la universidad, el problema es que el usuario debe poner la información (nombre de la materia, calificación, créditos) cada vez que abre el programa y quise automatizar esa parte por lo que usé 'fstream' para crear un archivo para cada una de estas variables (lo único que va a cambiar cada vez que el usuario use el programa es la calificación de cada materia por lo que no es necesario crear un archivo para estar variable, pero de todas maneras lo hice "para practicar" :D ).

Todo funciona muy bien pero ahora no sé cómo leer los datos del archivos y usarlos en el programa. Estaba pensando en crear un 'if' para preguntar al usuario si quiere usar las mismas materias y créditos o si quiere ingresar otras (en el caso de que haya pasado el semestre o un amigo quiera calcular su promedio ponderado), luego de recibir la respuesta del usuario, ¿cómo hago para usar la información ya guardada en los archivos? (asumiendo que el usuario ya usó el programa una vez por lo que dicha información ya está guardado en los archivos). 
En pocas palabras, cómo leer el archivo sabiendo que el de los nombres tiene palabras y el de los créditos tiene números? Aquí mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

#define NOTA_MIN 0.0f
#define NOTA_MAX 5.0f

#define CRED_MIN 0
#define CRED_MAX 10

int main(){
//Nombre del programa
cout << "\t\t Promedio Ponderado\n";

int num_Mat;
float sumCreditos = 0, sumPonderacion = 0;

// Solicita el numero de materias que luego es usado en el array
cout << "Ingrese el numero de materias\n";
cin >> num_Mat;
float notas [num_Mat];
int creditos [num_Mat];

// Archivo para guardar los nombres de las materias
ofstream file1;                                     // Lo crea
file1.open("Nombre de materias.txt");               // Lo abre y nombra

// Declara un array de tipo string con "n" elementos, definidos por la cantidad de materias
string nombres [num_Mat];

// Loop para obtener el nombre de las materias y guardarlas en el archivo
for (int i = 0; i < num_Mat; i++){
    cout << "Ingresa el nombre de la materia " << i+1 << endl; // "+1" porque no existe Materia 0
    cin >> nombres[i];
    file1 << nombres[i] << endl;
}

file1.close();                                      // Cierra el archivo 1

// Archivo para guardar las calificaciones
ofstream file2;                                     // Lo crea
file2.open("Calificaciones.txt");                         // Lo abre y nombra

// Archivo para guardar los creditos
ofstream file3;                                     // Lo crea
file3.open("Creditos.txt");                         // Lo abre y nombra

for (int i = 0; i < num_Mat; i++){
    cout << nombres[i] << ": \t" << endl;
    // Loop para obtener las calificaciones
    do {
        cout << "nota:\t\t";
        cin >> notas[i];
        file2 << notas[i] << endl;
        cin.clear();
    } while (notas[i] < NOTA_MIN || notas[i] > NOTA_MAX);

    // Loop para obtener los creditos
    do {
        cout << "credito:\t";
        cin >> creditos[i];
        file3 << creditos[i] << endl;
        cin.clear();
    } while (creditos[i] < CRED_MIN || creditos[i] > CRED_MAX);

   // sumar las notas*creditos y los creditos
    sumCreditos += creditos[i];
    sumPonderacion += notas[i] * creditos[i];
}
file2.close();                                      // Cierra el archivo 2
file3.close();                                      // Cierra el archivo 3

cout << "Tu promedio semestral es: " << sumPonderacion / sumCreditos << endl;
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Soy consciente de que mi código está un poco desordenado pero primero quiero terminar el programa y luego voy a optimizarlo y usar funciones para que quede mejor.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De forma similar a como has introducido los datos en los ficheros, pero ahora utilizando `ifstream`. Ahora irás leyendo los archivos y guardando su contenido en un vector.
Por ejemplo:

```
// Abrir archivo en modo lectura.
ifstream f_palabras ; 
f_palabras.open("Nombre de materias.txt"); 
// aquí se debería de hacer una comprobación de la correcta apertura.

// Vector para guardar los nombres
std::vector<string> nombres ;
string nombre ;

f_palabras >> nombre ; // usar getline(f_palabras, nombre) ; si el nombre es compuesto y leer así la linea completa

// Lectura del fichero hasta el final.
while(!f_palabras.eof()) {
    // inserta nombre en el vector
    nombres.push_back(nombre) ;
    f_palabras >> nombre ; // usar getline(f_palabras, nombre) ; si el nombre es compuesto y así leer la linea completa
}

f_palabras.close();
```

De igual forma se haría para guardar los créditos. Basta con cambiar las variables anteriores de `string` al tipo de dato numérico que te convenga (`double`, `int`...)

Comment: Prueba tu código porque no va a funcionar. `eof()` no se actualiza hasta que se realiza la primera lectura _sucia_. Es decir, `eof()` se activará **después** de `f_palabras>>nombre;` porque no se ha podido almacenar nada en `nombre`... en consecuencia la última palabra se almacenará **dos veces** en el vector

Comment: Arreglado, gracias.

Comment: Eso ya pinta mejor. Gracias por arreglarlo

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
string nombres [num_Mat];
```

Crear un array con tamaño basado en una variable es algo conocido como VLA (Variable Length Array) y es una característica **no permitida** en el estándar de C++. Si bien algunos compiladores y extensiones lo admiten yo no lo usaría so pena de ver como a la hora de la verdad tu programa falla sin remedio.

Para crear arrays de tamaño dinámico puedes o usar la memoria dinámica:

```
string *nombres = new string[num_Mat];
// ...
delete[] nombres;
```

o bien pasas a usar alguno de los múltiples contenedores disponibiles bajo el paraguas de la STL. El más genérico es `std::vector` que se adapta bastante bien a la mayoría de las situaciones:

```
// No hace falta indicarle el tamaño
std::vector<std::string> nombres;
nombres.push_back("abcd"); // Para añadir un elemento al final de la lista

// Aunque puedes crear un número inicial de elementos si asi lo deseas
std::vector<std::string> nombres(num_Mat);
nombres[1] = "abcd"; // acceder a los elementos se hace igual que en con los arreglos
```

Por otro lado, no se qué crees que hace `cin.clear();` pero ya te aviso que no borra lo que haya en el buffer de entrada. `cin.clear()` sirve para limpiar los bits de error del *stream*. Para limpiar el *buffer* debes usar el método `ignore()`:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
//       ^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^    ^^
//        (1)              (2)               (3)      (4)    (5)
```

Donde:

1. Método que permite descartar datos del *buffer*
2. Plantilla que permite recuperar los valores máximos y mínimos de cada tipo de datos. Se encuentra en `#include <limits>`
3. Nos interesa el rango de valores de `streamsize`, tipo utilizado de forma genérica para los *buffers* de entrada y salida (en 32 bits es equivalente a `unsigned int`).
4. Recuperamos el valor máximo admitido por el tipo anterior.
5. Se descartarán valores hasta el número indicado anteriormente o hasta llegar a un salto de línea (que también se descartará)

Bien, llegados a este punto, para leer los datos y almacenarlos en tu programa te tienes que plantear algunos detalles como el formato del fichero (que ya lo has decidido) y sus implicaciones. ¿Sabes cuántos registros tiene cada fichero? ¿Que ambos ficheros tengan el mismo número de registros es un requisito? ...

Para la primera pregunta puedo asumir que no lo sabes ya que no tiene pinta que, por ejemplo, el primer dato de cada fichero indique el número de elementos registrados en el fichero. Así pues lo más cómodo es usar un contenedor de la STL (Standard Template Library) para almacenar los datos según los vamos leyendo:

```
std::vector<float> notas;

std::ifstream fichNotas;
if( !fichNotas.open("Calificaciones.txt") )
{
  // No es posible abrir el fichero
}
else
{
  while( true )
  {
    float nota;
    fichNotas >> nota;
    if( fichNotas.good() && !fichNotas.eof() )
      notas.push_back(nota);
    else
      break; // Se ha detectado un error o hemos leido todo el fichero - dejamos de leer
  }
}
```

Y algo similar para leer el fichero de créditos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta y perdón por haber tardado tanto!
Pienso corregir el VLA más adelante, por ahora quiero concentrarme en otros aspectos como agregar funcionalidad. Sucede que esto lo voy a usar solo yo, al menos hasta que corrija los errores que usted me mostró. Por lo pronto estoy optimizando un poco más el programa y quiero implementar funciones para que sea más ordenado y ya me encontré con el primer error, por favor, lea mi respuesta más adelante.

Comment: Hola! Estoy tratando de implementar lo que me indicaste pero me encuentro con un pequeño inconveniente y es que como yo lo estaba haciendo, el usuario elegía la cantidad de materias y yo podía usar ese número para realizar el promedio; ahora en cambio, el usuario puede ingresar la cantidad de materias y no tengo cómo saber cuántas ingresó.
Una solución sería, pedir al usuario que ingrese la cantidad de materias y guardar el número en una variable entera. Otra solución, puede ser encontrar alguna forma de que el vector me indique cuántos elementos hay, pero esto posible? Gracias de antemano!

Comment: @GermánDiegoGuisasolaPlejo la clase [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) es lo que estás buscando

Comment: Ya lo encontré! De hecho, es `std::vector::size`. Muchas gracias, otra vez.

Comment: Una pregunta, es necesario poner `while( true )` en el último código que me enviaste? 
Y para qué sirve `fichNotas.good() && !fichNotas.eof()` ?
Gracias!

Comment: @GermánDiegoGuisasolaPlejo el `while` está así porque en ese momento no podemos comprobar si debemos abortar la lectura. Eso sólo se puede comprobar después de una operación de lectura... el `if` sirve para salir del bucle al leer todo el fichero o al producirse un error